# How does adding week result in Monday date only until Saturday?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using the following SQL to get latest Monday:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0) AS DATE)
```

`DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE())` gives 6374

By default SQL server week starts from Sunday. So how does adding 6374 weeks (or any number of weeks) to 0 give Monday?

I tried setting DATEFIRST to 1 to indicate week starts Monday. However, if today is Sunday then it gives the following Monday - whereas I want the previous Monday:

```
DECLARE @DT DATETIME
SET @DT='20220306'

SELECT CAST(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,@DT), 0) AS DATE)
```

Comment: Now you've completely [morphed this into a different question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) after you had two answers. Good luck.

Comment: What's "the latest Monday" if it actually is Monday? Should the outcome of that be "today" or "one week earlier"?

Comment: I mean if today is Sunday, then I want it to return Monday (from last week) assuming week starts Monday. Unfortunately datediff always starts with Sunday, so I guess the only solution to get Monday from the (mon-sun) period is to add -1 to @dt

Comment: Yes, but my question is what you want to happen if today is *Monday*. If `@DT = '2022-02-28'`, should the outcome be `2022-02-28` or `2022-02-21`?

Comment: The approach with the mysterious date 0 and subtracting weeks is not the only one, incidentally. `SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -((DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @DT) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7), @DT)` works by normalizing the weekday number and subtracting that, and has the benefit of working for any date/time type, in particular `DATE` itself. This does, however, assume that you want to get back the date itself if is a Monday, not the Monday before that.

Comment: If today is Monday then it should return today

Comment: How about `SELECT CAST(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,@DT-1), 0) AS DATE)`

Comment: How about it? Did you try it? Did it work? What's the question?

Comment: Yes indeed I did try it. Question is whether it is deterministic

Comment: Do you mean deterministic as in we can expect it to always work for any date throughout history, or do you mean deterministic like you could put that calculation into a computed column or user-defined function and that entity could be explicitly interpreted as being formally deterministic? (You could try both of those yourself, regardless.) Note that one query is riddled with problems: Lazy `wk` shorthand, just write `week`! Magic `0` date, just write a real date! Lazy `-1` which will fail on `date` types which it seems like you should be using. [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates).

Comment: `deterministic as in we can expect it to always work for any date throughout history` can you help me understand how to test this for all dates?

Comment: Two suggestions.... stop using the WK datatype, period.  It does NOT work the way most people think.  The first "week" of a year can be as short as 1 day as the last week of the year can be.  I also strongly recommend using any form of DATEFIRST.. it's just another unnecessary complication that you have to worry about folks getting right so that it works in a "deterministic" fashion as the OP stated above.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the previous Monday for weekdays that aren't Monday you can use this calculation

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, -(5+@@DATEFIRST+DATEPART(weekday,@DT))%7, @DT)
```

The `@@DATEFIRST` variable is used to make the calculation independent of the DATEFIRST setting.

For example :

> ```
> SET DATEFIRST 1
>
> SELECT DT
> , DATENAME(weekday, DT) as WeekdayName
> , DATEADD(day, -(5+@@DATEFIRST+DATEPART(weekday,[DT]))%7, [DT]) AS Monday
> , -(5+@@DATEFIRST+DATEPART(weekday,[DT]))%7 AS DowDiff
> , CAST(DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week,0,[DT]), 0) AS DATE) AS Df7Monday
> , DATEPART(week, [DT]) AS Week
> , DATEDIFF(week,0,[DT]) AS WeeksDiff
> FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> DT         | WeekdayName | Monday     | DowDiff | Df7Monday  | Week | WeeksDiff
> :--------- | :---------- | :--------- | ------: | :--------- | ---: | --------:
> 1900-01-01 | Monday      | 1900-01-01 |       0 | 1900-01-01 |    1 |         0
> 2022-02-27 | Sunday      | 2022-02-21 |      -6 | 2022-02-28 |    9 |      6374
> 2022-02-28 | Monday      | 2022-02-28 |       0 | 2022-02-28 |   10 |      6374
> 2022-03-01 | Tuesday     | 2022-02-28 |      -1 | 2022-02-28 |   10 |      6374
> 2022-03-02 | Wednesday   | 2022-02-28 |      -2 | 2022-02-28 |   10 |      6374
> 2022-03-03 | Thursday    | 2022-02-28 |      -3 | 2022-02-28 |   10 |      6374
> 2022-03-04 | Friday      | 2022-02-28 |      -4 | 2022-02-28 |   10 |      6374
> 2022-03-05 | Saturday    | 2022-02-28 |      -5 | 2022-02-28 |   10 |      6374
> 2022-03-06 | Sunday      | 2022-02-28 |      -6 | 2022-03-07 |   10 |      6375
> 2022-03-07 | Monday      | 2022-03-07 |       0 | 2022-03-07 |   11 |      6375
> ```

> ```
> SET DATEFIRST 7
>
> SELECT DT
> , DATENAME(weekday, DT) as WeekdayName
> , DATEADD(day, -(5+@@DATEFIRST+DATEPART(weekday,[DT]))%7, [DT]) AS Monday
> , -(5+@@DATEFIRST+DATEPART(weekday,[DT]))%7 AS DowDiff
> , CAST(DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week,0,[DT]), 0) AS DATE) AS Df7Monday
> , DATEPART(week, [DT]) AS Week
> , DATEDIFF(week,0,[DT]) AS WeeksDiff
> FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> DT         | WeekdayName | Monday     | DowDiff | Df7Monday  | Week | WeeksDiff
> :--------- | :---------- | :--------- | ------: | :--------- | ---: | --------:
> 1900-01-01 | Monday      | 1900-01-01 |       0 | 1900-01-01 |    1 |         0
> 2022-02-27 | Sunday      | 2022-02-21 |      -6 | 2022-02-28 |   10 |      6374
> 2022-02-28 | Monday      | 2022-02-28 |       0 | 2022-02-28 |   10 |      6374
> 2022-03-01 | Tuesday     | 2022-02-28 |      -1 | 2022-02-28 |   10 |      6374
> 2022-03-02 | Wednesday   | 2022-02-28 |      -2 | 2022-02-28 |   10 |      6374
> 2022-03-03 | Thursday    | 2022-02-28 |      -3 | 2022-02-28 |   10 |      6374
> 2022-03-04 | Friday      | 2022-02-28 |      -4 | 2022-02-28 |   10 |      6374
> 2022-03-05 | Saturday    | 2022-02-28 |      -5 | 2022-02-28 |   10 |      6374
> 2022-03-06 | Sunday      | 2022-02-28 |      -6 | 2022-03-07 |   11 |      6375
> 2022-03-07 | Monday      | 2022-03-07 |       0 | 2022-03-07 |   11 |      6375
> ```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7070aee18484142a6a1a2c8a104ebbf2)*

The calculation `DATEDIFF(wk,'1900-01-01',[DT])` is unaffected by the DATEFIRST setting.
Which you can see in the 2 test results.
Just compare Week & WeeksDiff for the date `2022-03-07`.

As @JeroenMostert pointed out, this is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-be/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks)

> Specifying SET DATEFIRST has no effect on DATEDIFF. DATEDIFF always
> uses Sunday as the first day of the week to ensure the function
> operates in a deterministic way.

Comment: How about `SELECT CAST(DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,@DT-1), 0) AS DATE) `? This is also inherently unaffected by DATEFIRST setting.

Comment: If added to the solution that I just don't know.  Logically one would assume that if `DATEPART(week, somedate)` depends on DATEFIRST that there would be a difference with `DATEDIFF(week,'1900-01-01', somedate)`. But tests show there isn't. It's against common sense.

Comment: @LukStorms: 1) common sense officially does not apply in T-SQL, otherwise you couldn't implicitly convert `0` to a `DATETIME` either and 2) the fact that `DATEDIFF` does *not* depend on `DATEFIRST` is [explicitly documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql#remarks).

Comment: @JeroenMostert As expected from you!  While I was having a walk I got pondering whether DATEFIRST simply didn't affect DATEDIFF as it would affect DATEPART. So that's how it is. Thanks!